Everything is ok but Firebase DB PUT request returns 400 Bad Request error
I am establishing HTTPS client connection to Firebase DB with STM32 and Mbedtls. I have checked data and headers and they seem all good. When I send GET request, connection is fine and i get 200 OK response with data. But if I write PUT request data with same body structure, server returns 400 BAD REQUEST with "error": "no data supplied" ... Is there a problem with request body that I am sending or the json data I am sending?
PUT request that is sent and return of 400 BAD REQUEST
. Setting up the SSL/TLS structure... ok

. Connecting to ecu.firebaseio.com at port: 443 ... ok

. Performing the SSL/TLS handshake... ok

. Verifying peer X.509 certificate... ok

 <Write to server: 272 bytes written

PUT /LAB/Temperatures.json?auth=[DATABASE SECRET] HTTP/1.1
Host: ecu.firebaseio.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Lenght: 75

{"Enclosure Temperatures" : "23.15", "MCU Temperatures" : "29.00"}

  < Read from server: 337 bytes read

                                    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:39:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 36
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

{
   "error" : "No data supplied."
                                }
                                  368 bytes read

                                                HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:39:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 150
Connection: close
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/source/ssl_msg.c:4681: mbedtls_ssl_fetch_input() returned -29312 (-0x7280)
                                                                                                             ../Middlewares/Third_Party/mbedTLS/source/ssl_msg.c:4046: ssl_get_next_record() returned -29312 (-0x7280)


                                              EOF

Successful GET request
. Verifying peer X.509 certificate... ok
                                               > Write to server: 169 bytes written

GET /Command/TV1.json?auth=[DATABASE SECRET] HTTP/1.1
Host: ecu.firebaseio.com
Content-lenght: 0
Connection: Close

  < Read from server: 303 bytes read

                                    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 23 Sep 2024 06:39:28 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 16
Connection: close
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload

{"Status":"OFF"}

The request body sent with MBEDTLS is like this..

sprintf(stringToProcess,"{\"Enclosure Temperatures\" : \"%.2f\", \"MCU Temperatures\" : \"%.2f\"}", enclosure_temp, mcu_temp);
strcpy(path, "/LAB/Temperatures.json?auth=");

if(req == get_req)
{
    len = sprintf((char*) buf, "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: %s\r\n"
                        "Content-lenght: 0\r\n"
                        "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n", path, SERVER_NAME);

}else if(req == put_req)
{

    len = sprintf((char*) buf, "PUT %s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                   "Host: %s\r\n"
                   "Content-Lenght: %d\r\n"
                   "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n"
                "%s", path, SERVER_NAME, strlen(stringToProcess), stringToProcess);
}

while((ret = mbedtls_ssl_write(&ssl, buf, len)) <= 0)
{
 if(ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_READ && ret != MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_WANT_WRITE)
    {
    mbedtls_printf(" failed\n  ! mbedtls_ssl_write returned %d\n\n", ret);
    goto exit;
    }
}

I tried adding some other headers and setting Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded but still got the same error. Also adding "\r\n" ending after json data in the request body didn't worked.

What is the request you send? With the little code (badly formatted, too), it's hard to guess. In any case, 400 means the receiver didn't like what you sent, which means that what you sent is probably wrong. So, in summary, please check the data you send and if you don't find anything, extract a [mcve] from your code for posting here. Also, consider creating the request using e.g. curl, where you can add the --verbose flag to see the actual outgoing data, too.

hi @UlrichEckhardt , thanks for your reply, I have edited the question with sent data and server response. I tested connection with same header and data set up using Python HTTP request and I have successfully written data to DB.
